# How to inject certain properties values during junit to a specific test

Tags: spring-boot, junit

My `Spring Boot` app has some test that are reading their properties from the `application.yml` that is in the `test` folder.

```
cat:
  maxAge:30
  maxNameSize:10
```

all is working fine, but I like that in certain tests, other values will be injected:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
    Cat.class
})
@SpringBootTest
public class CatTest {

   @Test
   public void testX(){
     //inject maxAge=90
     // use maxNameSize from the application.yml
     ....

   @Test
   public void testZ(){
     //inject maxNameSize=5 
     // use maxAge from the application.yml
     ....
}
```

Comment: i am not sure for a specifc test. But for an own class you can use https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html#properties--

Comment: Could you use `@Value` constructor args in your Spring Beans and then inject whatever value you want in the test?

Answer (score 1):

Changing properties on method level is not supported by Spring at this moment.

You can use nested classes to accomplish this.

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
    Cat.class
})
@SpringBootTest
public class CatTest {

    @Nested
    @SpringBootTest(properties = "cat.maxAge=90")
    public class NestedTestX {
    
        @Test
        void testX() {
            //noop
        }
    }

    @Nested
    @SpringBootTest(properties = "cat.maxNameSize=5")
    public class NestedTestZ {

        @Test
        void testZ() {
            //noop
        }
    }

}
```